# Can I make profitable app for Ubuntu Touch?

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch, paid-applications

I would like to ask you guys, if there would be some sort of app policy regarding the Ubuntu touch. Just as in Android, and iOS, the developers could earn a reasonable amount of money, by making their applications paid for, or by placing adds in the app. Will this kind of things available in the Ubuntu Touch, or the app ecosystem will be only allowing free open source applications?

<sub>**(I am not talking about the big paid for projects made by the big guns, just the one men projects)**</sub>

Comment: http://developer.ubuntu.com/2013/08/software-store-for-click-packages-now-open-for-testing/ ,  http://developer.ubuntu.com/publish/ so yes there will be paid apps.

Comment: @Mateo Do you think you could expand those links into an answer? :)

Answer (score 5):

Currently Ubuntu Touch is in development and many of these details are not yet worked out.

---

*Will the app ecosystem only allow free open source applications?*

- You can publish your app under any number of licenses including **Proprietary**

  [image: License drop menu showing various licenses]

---

*Can you make your app a paid app?*

- At http://developer.ubuntu.com/publish/ #4 states:

  > ### Choose your price
  >
  > Not all software is free in the Software Centre. If you are charging
  >   for your app, you’ll need to provide details of your Paypal account, a
  >   phone number and a postal address. The minimum price you can charge is
  >   $2.99.
  >
  > **Note:** for mobile apps in the Software Store Beta, payments are not yet enabled, so stay tuned for updates on when you can start charging
  >   for your app.

  And also show a graph of the fees you need to pay if you choose to charge:
  [image: Pie chart with labels 80% for you 20% for us]

  The **Note** is important because it refers to *Software Store Beta* which is currently what you can use to get apps to the Ubuntu Touch Developer Preview. However payments are not yet in place.

---

*Can you place ads in the app?*

This question is probably the hardest to answer at the moment, because at the moment it seems there is no "ad system". This would be important for many reasons:

1. It would be similar to *spyware* if a individual application would access and deliver information for placing ads, as well as resource consuming if many apps were doing it at once.
2. Need of approved ads, ones that would not hack/crash/do any buffer-overflow/automatically install programs/ect. or  mislead to "Download Here" when a real download link is elsewhere.
3. Acceptable ad area, so we don't encourage targeting accidental clicks or guerrilla tactics that only frustrate users (are they really going to buy/download a product they were practically forced to click on). Possible area for banner format ads when you look at the design of many of the current apps:

   [image]

   <sub>***Note:*** Just a mock-up and not actual ad placement or views of developers, nor am I saying there should be ads in the clock app.</sub>

There are many discussions about how it should be, but I think many free apps that are currently are for Android show how it shouldn't be: Requiring every kind of permission (and they say that is only to serve ads), pop up videos, slide in graphics, Begging for ratings, you name it - Will Ubuntu Touch be the same "anything goes" in this aspect?

Or will there be no ads allowed altogether - In favor of trial (of which can be added to the software center) and paid versions, or altogether free.

Possibly a framework for ads could made as [hbdgaf suggested in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/11000032#11000032) :

> So it was said it isn't ad driven. It should be. Not putting ads in
>   lenses, but a way to get something google-esque with an ad framework
>   integrated in to the app framework. Say I want to make a cool app for
>   u-touch and not get paid for it. Ad funding should be an option. Maybe
>   it still is, but ad is a hot-word so they left it alone and said it's
>   not a thing. Just saying... A framework should be in place. It isn't.
>   This is a way to get there from here.

For now it seems in the developer preview they are focusing on the "Core" apps and experience, and we have not yet seen how the paid/ad system will look.

Comment: Some news on this since 2013? Now as the first few ubuntu phones are told app development has to get somehow attractive...

Comment: Yes, charging for an app now works @lukasstr however I'm not sure if they have any policies about "freemium" or ad supported... This post was basically opinions the subject

Comment: I wonder if it's possible to create a html5 app and simply place adsense ads inside it.

Comment: The apps now have the ability for "in apps purchaces"